# Piksi Rtk || C++ || Windows 10

Tags: c++, gps

I am trying to get data from Piksi rtk kit using C++ in Visual studio in Windows 10. I am using the libsbp library.

But I am unable to compile the C example in C++,. I have also attached a screenshot of the errors.

It would be help me greatly if anyone could provide any directions how to use it.

Thanks,
Amit

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkHiT.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it helps, but I know that for Python it should be possible, and I am going to work on it soon :-)

http://docs.swiftnav.com/wiki/Reading_SBP_data_from_Piksi_with_a_simple_client